# Converting datetime data on retrieval with user's timezone using date mutators in Laravel 5

Tags: datetime, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'm saving all datetime data (created_at, updated_at and a custom datetime column: appointment_at) in UTC format.

I would like to retrieve all these dates, and convert them to the user's timezone for display.

I've added these functions to my model thinking this would retrieve the datetime in the user's timezone:

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $created_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $updated_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}

public function getAppointmentAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $appointment_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Call to a member function timezone() on a non-object
```

I'm guessing there's an error in my syntax. Am I missing something? Thanks

**UPDATE #1 Made corrections to Note Model and added complete Model below (including corrections by @bernie)**

```
<?php namespace App;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Note extends Model {


/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'notes';


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['client_id', 'business_id', 'note'];


/**
 * Note belonging to client.
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
}


public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->created_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);     
}   

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->updated_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);     
}   

public function getAppointmentAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->appointment_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);     
}
```

**Database Model definition**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateNotesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('notes', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('business_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('business_id')->references('id')->on('businesses')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->text('note');
            $table->dateTime('appointment_at');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('notes');
    }

}
```

**More info about the error (after updates by bernie)**

```
 ErrorException in Note.php line 40: Undefined property: App\Note::$created_at

in Note.php line 40
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined property: App\Note::$created_at', '/var/www/html/laravel5/app/Note.php', '40', array()) in Note.php line 40
at Note->getCreatedAtAttribute('2015-09-22 12:50:20') in Model.php line 2669
at Model->mutateAttribute('created_at', '2015-09-22 12:50:20') in Model.php line 2592
at Model->getAttributeValue('created_at') in Model.php line 2557
at Model->getAttribute('created_at') in Model.php line 3263
at Model->__get('created_at') in NotesController.php line 54
at NotesController->show('1')
```

**Solution**

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $date = $this->asDateTime($value);
    return $date->timezone(\Auth::user()->timezone);
}
```

or

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $format = $this->getDateFormat();      
    return  Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $value, 'UTC')->setTimezone( \Auth::user()->timezone);
}
```

Both of these solutions worked for me.

Comment: Check the database definition. Are these fields `TIMESTAMP` columns? It they are, do a `print_r` on your Note instance to see what values you're getting from teh database.

Comment: Yes, timestamps() created the two following TIMESTAMP columns: created_at and updated_at.

Comment: That print_r could hopefully reveal the cause. Another idea: show the surrounding code where you're calling getCreatedAtAttribute(). (btw, why is there a $value parameter?) Are you using a Note retrieved from the database or a new one you created?

Comment: `print_r($this->created_at);` outputs the same error. But i've added more information about the error (see above). It's a Note i'm retrieving from the database I'm trying to get. Oh I guess $value is not needed (sorry, code copied from elsewhere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah now I see! I realized you're using [*Accessors and Mutators*](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). You're also overriding the built-in [date mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) used for created_at and other `dates` fields.

So, try this instead :

```
public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    // asDateTime() is the built-in date mutator.
    $date = $this->asDateTime($value);
    return $date->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}

public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
{
    $date = $this->asDateTime($value);
    return $date->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}

public function getAppointmentAtAttribute($value)
{
    $date = $this->asDateTime($value);
    return $date->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it and I get `Undefined property: App\Note::$created_at` for my Note model. `at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined property: App\Note::$created_at', '/var/www/html/laravel5/app/Note.php', '44', array('value' => '2015-09-22 12:50:20')) in Note.php line 44`

Comment: Hi @bernie, i've added my model (see above)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to ask for the Model's database table definition (your migration perhaps)

Comment: I've added my db model definition

Comment: I think you did `$this->$created_at` (note the second $) instead of `$this->created_at`. Also see updated answer

Comment: I see what you mean, but no, I get `Undefined property: App\Note::$created_at` with `return $this->created_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);` and not sure why

Comment: It works! Had a problem, but it was my fault. Thanks for your help.. and patience @bernie !