# Convert day and time for timezone with no definite date in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, timezone

I'm trying to convert day and time from timezone to timezone. Basically, the form asks for the user's available day and time indefinitely (ex. every Monday 8 am or Tuesday 4pm) so that other users can book an appointment during these weekly available times. How do I convert the time just so when someone from the Philippines sets an available day of Monday 1pm, it shows up as Monday 3pm for Melbourne, Australia users? Is there a way to convert the day as well (ex. Monday 11pm for PH time is Tuesday 1am Au time)? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting datetime data on retrieval with user's timezone using date mutators in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719004/converting-datetime-data-on-retrieval-with-users-timezone-using-date-mutators-i)

Comment: @DhanaD. sadly, i dont think so. i have to convert available times with no definite dates (ie monday 1pm for australian time should display monday 11 am for ph time). if i am correct, my input of available time (1 AM) is a string since there is no no definite date for it. do you maybe know how i could work around it?